# Regex to replace specific expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an regex to replace some input, this is the input 
`{{number}}-{{$index}}`

And i want transform to 
`result = ["{{number}}", "{{$index}}"]`

I trying with this regex `({{).*?(}})` but don't give me what i'm expect

Comment: What language are you using? What is the replacement string you're using?

Comment: Are `number` and `$index` literal strings, or are they variable?

Comment: I'm using javascript, they are variables

Comment: Add the language tag and post your code.

Comment: From the way this is worded, it looks like you could do `result = input.split("-")`

Comment: I'm just try to using a regex to modify the variable content, they come with this symbols, i'm sorry they are not variables, they are a literal string and i want apply this regex to transform

Comment: @JoãoVictorCanabarro can you **explain your intent**? It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish. Take a step back and read your question as if you have no preconceived knowledge about the task at hand.

Comment: The string `{{number}}-{{$index}}` comes for a outside function, but between `{{number}}` and ` {{$index}}` could has anything and i want remove this and just take this 2 parts of the text, just only that

Comment: Just match on [`{{[^{}]*}}`](https://regex101.com/r/nxl5GC/1) and if you want to match single `{` or `}` inside those brackets use [`{{(?:(?!{{|}}).)*}}`](https://regex101.com/r/nxl5GC/2)

Comment: Does one of the variables contain { or }?

Comment: @ctwheels Could you please add this to the answer of the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract all `{{x}}` where `x` can be any character except `{` or `}` you can use the following:

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/nxl5GC/3)

```
{{[^{}]*}}
```

- `{{` Match this literally
- `[^{}]*` Match any character except `{` or `}` any number of times
- `}}` Match this literally

Similarly, the following regex does the same as the previous but allows single `{` and `}`, but not double `{{` or `}}`:

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/nxl5GC/4)

```
{{(?:(?!{{|}}).)*}}
```

- `{{` Match this literally
- `(?:(?!{{|}}).)*` Match any character any number of times except where `{{` or `}}` exists. This is called a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794).
- `}}` Match this literally

For a *very slight* performance gain, you can substitute each instance of `{{` for `{{2}` and each instance of `}}` for `}{2}`.

Comment: You may add `(` and `)` for grouping